# Assign class property in one function and use it in another function in php

Tags: php, oop

Please consider this class, I have an *html page* with two forms, first i submit `form1` and after that I submit second one. I change `$aaa` value in first function but after submitting second form, it show **empty array** and lost assigned value in `func1`.
I want to access `func1` assigned value in `func2`.

```
class Myclass
{
    private $aaa = array();

    public function func1() {
        $this->aaa= [1, 2, 3];
    }

    public function func2() {
        var_dump($this->aaa);
    }
}
```

---

In the HTML file:

```
<form action=" FUNC1 " method="post" id="form1">
    <button type="submit">FUNC1</button>
</form>

<form action=" FUNC2 " method="post" id="form2">
    <button type="submit">FUNC2</button>
</form>
```

Comment: php is stateless, it won't automatically maintain data between form posts.  You have to find a way to maintain application state yourself, by saving data to a database, a session, or passing it back and forth with the client.

Comment: as Mark H. said, as PHP is stateless when you load the controller again for the second form you will lose the values. I would suggest using func1() to save the data to the session if you are working with sessions.

Comment: What is the best way to pass an array? Is session a good way?

Comment: Session is a good way. There isn't just one "best" way, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass
{

public function __construct(
    $closure
) {
    $this->aaa = $closure();
}

public function func1() ....
```

You can now hold your data inside a session individual to that users browser

```
session_start();
$myClass = new MyClass(function () use($_SESSION) { if(isset($_SESSION['index_here'])) { return $_SESSION['index_here']; } });
```

Then the same when appending or changing the object property aaa - update the session